# How do you copy files from server a to ssh'd server b?

Tags: files, scp

I have to ssh into Server A and then ssh into Server B to apply database upgrades; unfortunately, I am unable to use get or wget to stage my upgrade files.  Is there a way, in Linux, to move files from Server A to Server B?  I was able to scp the files to Server A, but have not found a way to get them on the DB Server (Server B).

Comment: If you can ssh into Server B, you should be able to scp into it, too.  What happens when you try?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: See `man scp` for the different options available for use with this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `scp` to do what you want:

```
scp mimifarmer@servera:/path/to/file mimi@serverb:
```

To do this, you need to have the `openssh-clients` package installed in both machines.